# Angular 2 components inside ngFor are not updated

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm struggling for a few hours trying to update the view of my list of item.

I have a component called `document-list`.
This component goes through each document passed to it and include a component called `document-list-item`.

```
<div *ngFor="let document of documents">
    <document-list-item [document]="document"></document-list-item>
</div>
```

When I update the list of document, the children views are not updated.

I tried those in the `documents` accessor of the `document-list` component :

```
public set documents(value: DocumentDetails[]) {
    this._documents = value;
    // used one by one
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); => doesn't work
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck(); => doesn't work
    this.appRef.tick(); => throw an error about recursivity
}
```

I also tried to manually update the list in the setters (well placed console.log showed me that it goes in) :

```
private _documents: DocumentDetails[] = [];
@Input()
public set documents(value: DocumentDetails[]) {
    this._documents = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        this._documents[i] = value[i];
    }
}
public get documents() {
    return this._documents;
}
```

The only thing that works was doing this in the accessor :

```
public set documents(value: DocumentDetails[]) {
    this.documents = [];
    setTimeout(() => {
        this._documents = value;
    }, 0);
}
```

It worked but it showed a blinking list each time the documents array were updated, which is not acceptable.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AZhKuZnFYqWbRekmMLwd?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you fill `this._documents` array, not `this.documents` in component, but in html you use `documents`

Comment: How do you set `documents`?

Comment: `<document-list [documents]="myMainObject.documents">
</document-list>`
@Maxim : I'm using getters and setters so when you request this.documents, it's actually this._documents that you receive. I know my documents object is updated and goes through the setters (I did a console.log and checked that values are correct). 
It's hard for me to do a plunkr because it's much more complicated than that. But I know that my document list is updated, so I want a way to force a redraw of the list.

Comment: try using trackBy `*ngFor="let document of documents trackBy:document.id"`

Comment: just tried `;trackBy: document?.id` but no success (had to add the question mark)

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
<document-list-item [document]="document"></document-list-item>
```

So you should have in your child class:

```
@Input()
document: any;
```

Comment: I think it's obvious I have this in the child document. Otherwise the problem wouldn't be the update but rather the create :)

Comment: So are you sur that this ngFor works well? If you display directly some content of the document in the html, is it updating?

Comment: The list is working perfectly and shows what it should show. The problem is when I update one of the element in an other component. The object containing the list of documents is updated but not the view